# Grammar injections in Monaco?

Tags: monaco-editor

Any idea how I'd accomplish injecting a TextMate grammar into an existing Monarch grammar (as indicated here: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#injection-grammars) using Monaco's API?

Basically, I'm trying to bring vscode-styled-components's functionality over to Monaco, and I'm at a loss for how to do it. I've studied the code responsible for registering extension grammar contributions, as well as the code for tokenization, and I just can't quite figure out how it all connects.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible. TextMate grammars are an addition to Monaco from vscode. You will have to parse and convert the grammars yourself to load them into Monaco.

Comment: So, there is this library (https://github.com/bolinfest/monaco-tm) which brings TextMate grammars into Monaco. Would that change your answer at all? It works with standalone languages perfectly, so it seems to me that it should work with grammar injections?

Comment: Or, are you saying that it's not possible to inject TextMate grammars into Monarch grammars. Which would make sense, however it does appear to be happening in VSCode (unless within VSCode there's a TextMate version of the JavaScript grammar which is used when extensions are injecting additional grammar into it?)

Comment: That tool monaco-tm is an external lib that does the same as what vscode has (using the same 3rd party libs). With additional libs you can basically do anything, including writing a second vscode. I assumed you wanted to know how to import TM grammars natively in monaco-editor. And by using monaco-tm you are actually doing what I recommended: parse and convert yourself.